# Save CoffeeScript json object data inside a Rails variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, coffeescript

I have a js.coffee.erb file and in this file there is a function which gets a 'equipment' json object (in javascript) and pastes some of the data to the html.
the json object is saved in variable called `eqp`.

Each equipment has a `category` (reference to other table object).
In the json object, there is only the `equipment.category_id`, so to get the category name I wrote this statement:

```
$("#display_equipment_category_value").html <%= Category.find(eqp.category_id).name %>
```

The problem is that it can't defined a rails variable called `eqp` because it's not a rails object.

How could I save the js json `eqp.category_id` inside a rails variable?

```
set_equipment = (eqp) -> 
    <% cat_id =  ?????  %>      -     # save the eqp.category_id into cat_id
    $("#display_equipment_category_value").html <%= Category.find(cat_id).name %>
```

Comment: No way. Rails runs at server and java/coffeescript run at client.
If You want to transmit data from client to server, You can use ajax queries, but they are requires new routes and controller methods at server.

Comment: Is this CoffeeScript a client side JavaScript file or rendered by `respond_to` block?

Comment: haa.. ok I understand. so how should I solve my problem of showing the category name? should I bring all categories and compare to the category_id in the client side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the correct answer because it seems to be ineffective, but it works fine so I'll use it:

```
set_equipment = (eqp) -> 

    // Creating an empty string variable for the result category name
    cat = "";


    // Bringing all categories from DB and save them as a json object

    <% all_cat = Category.all %>
    categories = <%= all_cat.to_json %>


    // Comparing each category to the equipment category_id

    $.each categories, (i, v) =>
        cat = v.name if (v.id == eqp.category_id) 


    // Display the category name in the html

    $("#display_equipment_category_value").html cat
```

Comment: NOTE: if that code is in a coffeescript file the erb code will be evaluated once (during asset compilation) only and probably not what you want. In development environment it will be re-evaluated every time you change the code